# How can I avoid using the optional resolve option in config for Webpack 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I'm playing with the newly released second version of Webpack. I got the following error message.

> Invalid configuration object... These properties are valid:
>   object { amd?, bail?, ..., devtool?, **entry**, ..., output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, **resolve?**, ... }

I also got the following error.

> configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.

This is confusing because in the first message, it's implied by the question mark that *resolve* is optional (as opposed to the other highlighted option *entry* which is required, as indicated by the absence of the question mark).

Am I ignorant of the meaning of the question mark in this context? Is it a typo? Did I get confused by something totally different?

Comment: This is going to be easier to debug if you show us your config file...I assume you don't have resolve in there?

Comment: @thesublimeobject I see that I wasn't stressing the **type** of question enough. I'm not asking how to resolve it. I'm asking about the error saying that I mustn't have an empty such element versus the optionality of said element. Kind of inconsequent implementation in my view (which might be totally of).

Comment: Well, that's kind of why I was asking: I'm still not sure whether your config has an _empty_ resolve object or _no_ resolve object. In the former case I can see it legitimately throwing an error of the type, if you have this object at all it must have the prop extension; although if it's the latter, I would understand your confusion. And if it is the latter, it might be better to open an issue on the repo?

Comment: @thesublimeobject Oh, my apologies. I missed that difference. My bad. I tested with **no resolve** and with **filled resolve**. I totally missed the case of existing but empty option. Good thinking. So I guess I should report it, as you say. Problem is that I'm not entirely certain how and I'm modest enough to suspect that it's not a bug but rather my incompetence that's the cause behind it, hehe.

Comment: If you're interested, I just ran my config with all three variations you just mentioned and didn't get any errors...so I'm out of suggestions for you. Haha.

Comment: @thesublimeobject Interesting. I'll look into it as soon as I get home. It's probably due to some other stuff in the config file. Are you running the latest version of Webpack? I have 2.2.1 at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on the same version. I actually looked through the source code for their config validation, and there did not seem to be anything preventing you from omitting a resolve prop. I am going to guess that it's something else in the config file as well.

Comment: @thesublimeobject Not sure about that. However, now I've played around and when I type in *resolve: { root: [] }*, I get that *root* isn't valid for that option. However, in [docs for Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve), they say it's supposed to be there. They even show an example (using *path*)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to put this under answer because I think I've solved your real issue:

new webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/

**EDIT**: Specifically, https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: Are you saying that I've spend four hours of my birthday fighting the stupid Webpack version 2 while armed with the stupid docs of Webpack 1?! I can't be **that** stupid! It even says on the top of the page that Webpack 1 is obsolete and Webpack 2 should be used.

Comment: Oh, wait. I just read the second column that was hidden on my small screen. They actually state that one should follow a link to the other documentation page. There is a word I choose not to utter right now but they are four-letters long and rhyme with a bird that says *quack*.

Comment: Haha. Glad we got it figured out though...I didn't figure out there was a second set of docs except on accident one day, so don't feel too bad.

Answer (score 1):

@thesublimeobject's answer links to the right documentation. I had the same problem and solved it following their suggestions. I thought I'd contribute some of my webpack config by way of example.

I had to add the following `resolve` block:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
}
```

I also had to update my modules definition to catch .JSX files:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
    }]
},
```

Note I've added an optional 'x' to the regex file extension matcher. This gave me a configuration that allowed me to have files ending in ".jsx", but imported without identifying the extension.

```
import Widget from './components/Widget';
```

Whilst not explicit, I feel this improves readability. It also allows SublimeText to always use [Babel's JavaScript (Babel) code highlighting](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) for files containing JSX.

### Why this way?

As per the docs, the resolver now has these defaults:

```
resolve: {
    enforceExtension: false,
    extensions: ['.js', '.json']
}
```

This allows for importing files using either of the specified extensions OR no extension. If you provide a new `extensions` collection, it will override the default. So, to retain the defaults as well as your new requirements, you need to include all the defaults explicitly.